# Creating a procedural continuous trail following an object

Tags: modifiers, particles, geometry-nodes, tracking, procedural

I haven't found a single post which results in an actual trail so i tried making one a while ago; [(Render of my old system)](https://youtu.be/wGKgh6clgyY). But it would break easily and the trail would flip orientation randomly, so there was very little opportunity for creativity. Still this is a good resource to have and I recently lost a large amount of my old projects, so I tried to recreate it and i got a far better result. Its actually (mostly) stable now :)

It uses particle instancing and geometry node.
**First you make a particle emitter**, it only seems to work properly on **Newtonian physics** so you will need to disable stuff like gravity and force field weights if you want a stationary trail. But this also allows for more creative stuff; like a strand of string being blown away in the wind.

I use a **4:1 ratio of particles to frames**, so a 250 frame video would have 1000 total particles in the simulation. If you use less total particles than frames the trail will start snapping instead of smoothly following the path and it can generally start bugging out.
[image]

After you have created your base particle trail (I recommend using a single vertex as the emitter), Create a second object. **This one needs to be a single vertex for the geometry nodes to work**.

Put a **Particle Instance Modifier** on the second object and set it to the first object's particle system. Copy the settings in the image.
**Note that this is on Blender version 3.4, So if you are using an older version, replace the Sample Index node with a transfer attribute.**
[image]

Next, create a **geometry node modifier** and **copy the nodes** here, sorry for low resolution
[image]

**UV and shape of final product**
[image]

**UV is broken** since I don't know how to bypass the cyclic line's automatic colouring.
[image]

And Finally a proof that this actually works, tried some wind effects.
[image]

Comment: Interesting hack, very similar but a different method of the buffer one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=By4wsOR7DVA

Comment: That looks very good and far more stable than my suggestion, but i get the feeling that it would be slower and harder to work with when actually animating. Also thanks for showing me the looping thing, I've been looking on how to do that since geometry nodes were released.

Comment: If you are interested in the "loop thing" it is now a branch of development named "3.5-geometry-nodes-simulation": https://builder.blender.org/download/experimental/

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.  They may not want to create the node setup from scratch.